# WPF DataBinding: Nullable Int still gets a validation error?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding

I have a textbox databound to a nullable int through code. If I erase the data from the textbox it gives me a validation error (red border around it).

Here is my binding code:

```
ZipBinding = new Binding("Zip");
ZipBinding.Source = Address;
zipTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, ZipBinding);

public Int32? Zip { get { ... } set { ... } }
```

It's clearly marked as a Nullable so why does WPF wanna give me a validation issue when I clear the textbox?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Validation is failing because it can't convert the empty string to a nullable integer.  Set [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx) to string.empty on the Binding and it will convert the empty string to null, which will be valid.

Comment: Works great! See this answer for how to do it in XAML http://stackoverflow.com/a/1895482/83111

Comment: Don't set it to String.Empty, because then you see the text "String.Empty" in the field for null values in the model.
Use an empty String instead.

Example:
`<TextBox Text="{Binding MyNumericProperty, TargetNullValue=''}" />`

Comment: @Beauty you can set it to string.Empty: `<TextBox Text="{Binding MyNumericProperty, TargetNullValue={x:Static system:String.Empty}}" />` (including system at the header of the UserControl: `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`). This is different to setting it to a string whose value is "string.Empty"... much like when someone tells you to set a string to null, you don't do `username = "null";`.

Answer (score 0):

An empty TextBox != null.

You may have to tweak the ValidationRule to accommodate empty strings as entries.  Or, you could create a converter to take empty strings and convert them to null.

Comment: So it's failing because it's trying to parse String.Empty into an Int32? ... If that's the case then yea, I guess I'll have to create a StringEmpty to Null Converter.