# Must have non-null value for 'Binding'

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to use a special binding for comparisons found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehillberg/2008/09/30/a-comparable-datatrigger/) and recommended on another question. `NEQ` is an added operator that just gives the opposite result of `EQ`. An `InvalidOperationException` is thrown every time with the message "Must have non-null value for 'Binding'".

I've tried reducing the statements to just `{Binding SourceExpanded}` in the condition for testing and even that throws the same exception.

`Source`, `SourceExpanded`, and `SourceCollapsed` are all dependency properties defined in the class this style is associated with.

Is the issue, that you can't bind to a dependency property with a null value? And if so, why is the property value not allowed to be null?

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Binding="{local:ComparisonBinding SourceCollapsed, NEQ, {x:Null}}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding SourceExpanded}"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsExpanded" Value="False"/>
            <Condition Binding="{local:ComparisonBinding SourceCollapsed, NEQ, {x:Null}}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding SourceCollapsed}"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it is kind of late, you must have solved your problem, if not, here is how to solve it.

You need to change 
`<Condition Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>` to 
`<Condition Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />`

Comment: I have tried your solution on a simple TextBlock, and it doesn't work, same exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [Ray's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53186132/2315856) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1895482/2315856) answer: for the `MultiDataTrigger` `Condition` element, use explicit `Binding` instead of `Property`, and define a default value if null, using `TargetNullValue`. Here is the code:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, TargetNullValue=''}" Value="True"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```